# prove that the supremum is $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

show that 
$$\sup\{x\in \Bbb Q :x>0,x^2<2\}=\sqrt{2}$$

I have the solution but it is too complicated can someone explain it to me in a simple way?
I would really appreciate it
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the definition of a supremum handy?  Could any real number strictly less than $\sqrt{2}$ satisfy the conditions?  Could any real number strictly greater than $\sqrt{2}$ satisfy the conditions?  Remember the density of the rational numbers.

Comment: "I have the solution but it is too complicated can someone explain it to me in a simple way?" To make this question answerable include this solution and say what you want explained specifically. You can [edit] the post.

Comment: Personally, I'd call $\lambda$ that number and proceed by showing, according to the definition of $\sup$, that $\lambda\ge0$ and that $\lambda^2=2$. In order to do this, I'd probably need to do some backward esitmates which I would make up on spot. However, since "geniuses tend to have similar ideas", I suspect I'd come up with something not substantially different from your book.

Comment: This because my educate guess on the context of the question is that it is not asking "*We know that there is a real number* $\lambda\in\Bbb R_+$ *such that* $\lambda^2=2$*: prove that it is actually this* $\sup$", but "*Use the existence of this* $\sup$ *to prove that there is a* $\lambda\in\Bbb R_+$ *such that* $\lambda^2=2$". Of course, I am no clairvoyant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, $\sqrt{2}$ is an upperbound of this set. This is because for all $x$ in the set, $x^2\lt (\sqrt2)^2$ by definition.

Now, it needs to be shown that this is the least upper bound, or the supremum.

Suppose this is not the case. Let some $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$ be the supremum, where $\alpha$ must be less than $\sqrt2$, as $\sqrt2$ is an upper bound.

So, $$\alpha\lt \sqrt2$$
By the denseness of rationals, there exists some $y\in\mathbb Q$ such that
$$\alpha\lt y\lt \sqrt2$$

But now, we have $y\in\mathbb Q$ and $$\alpha^2\lt y^2\lt 2$$ i.e, $y^2\lt 2$.

We have managed to find an element of the set, $y$, that is greater than the supremum, $\alpha$. This goes against the definition of a supremum, and is a contradiction.

Hence, the supremum of the set is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: rationals are not dense

Comment: @jaja Rationals are dense in the reals, see the examples section here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set