# Showing that $\sup \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 < 2\} = \sqrt{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^{2} < 2\}$. How to prove $\sup(A)=2^{1/2}$?

I can prove $2^{1/2}$ is an upper bound for $A$.

But I can't prove the next condition in the definition of the supremum.

Comment: What is the wording for the theorem that you are using? (How may we know which part is the "next" part?)

Comment: I believe this link should be of use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169201/prove-that-the-supremum-is-sqrt2. The answer given here is particularly good.

Comment: forall $x\in A, x<\sqrt 2$ and there exists a sequence of $x_n$ that converges to $\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 1):

Establish that *any* positive real number strictly less than $2^{1/2}$ will be *in* the set $\{x:x^2<2\}$ *and not* an upper bound of the set, because $\forall y~((0<y<2^{1/2})\to\exists z~(y^2<z^2<2))$, due to *some* property of the real numbers.   You can then be sure that there can not exist any other upper bounds between $2^{1/2}$ and $A$.

( I am so dense.   What is that property called again?)