# Proof of supremum of rationals less than $\sqrt 2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $ A= \lbrace x\in \mathbb{Q}: x>0, x^2 < 2 \rbrace$.  Show that $s=\sup{A}=\sqrt{2}$.

Here is the proof I came up with (after of course proving that $A$ has a least upper bound).  Where am I going wrong here?  Am I making unwarranted assumptions?  If my proof makes sense, why is Kaczor’s much more involved?  I am an amateur self studying analysis so any help appreciated…

Suppose $s < \sqrt{2}$. By density of rational numbers in the reals, there exists a rational number $a$ such that $s < a < \sqrt{2} \rightarrow s^2 < a^2 < 2 \rightarrow s \neq \sup{A}$.  I would give a similar argument for the reverse inequality to prove equality.

For reference, here is the proof from Kaczor’s analysis problem book:

[image]

In response to fleablood’s comment about the line in Kaczor’s solution, I think the reason is:

$0 < [(n+1)s]-(n+1)s +1 \leq 1 \rightarrow s < w$

In general, I find these foundational type problems difficult as it’s unclear what’s assumed and what isn’t.  I am guessing the issue here is I can’t assume the density of the rationals (but then again the author invokes a limiting argument before that concept is introduced…).

Thanks.

Comment: It seems fine to me at first glance. The only nitpick I could make is that $s \not < \sqrt 2$ and $s \not > \sqrt 2$ does not necessarily mean $s = \sqrt 2$ unless you know that $s$ exists in the first place. But I imagine that can be almost taken as a given, considering the least-upper-bound property of the reals. (Of course, you would typically simply show that $\sqrt 2$ is an upper bound, and is the least upper bound in particular, to give it as the supremum, a la [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169201/prove-that-the-supremum-is-sqrt2).)

Comment: By the way, your earlier version of the post where you had

$$s < a < \sqrt 2 \implies s^2 < a^2 < 2 \implies s \ne \sup(A)$$

was the correct formulation. (You have that $a$ is a positive rational less than $\sqrt 2$ in $A$ but exceeding $s$, contradicting that $s = \sup(A)$.) The current version stating $s \not < 2$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks on both comments.  The solution for this in Kaczor’s analysis problem text is a lot more involved so I am not sure if I am making some assumptions that are not allowed but it’s just a problem text so it is unclear.

Comment: If you edit the solution they give into the question body, maybe someone can enlighten you as to why they do the things they do.

Comment: You should explain why $w > s$.