# Are there alternatives to Rudin's proof that $\sup \{ p\in\mathbb{ Q}^+\mid p^2<2 \} =\sqrt 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

I am familiar with Rudin's proof  that $\sup \{ p\in\mathbb{ Q}^+\mid p^2<2 \} =\sqrt 2$ ?

> Let $A$ be the set of all positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2 < 2$ and let $В$ consist of all positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2 > 2$. We shall show that $A$ contains no largest number and $В$ contains no smallest.
> More explicitly, for every $p \in A$ we can find a rational $q \in A$ such that $p < q$, and for every $p \in В$ we can find a rational $q \in В$ such that $q < p$.
> To do this, we associate with each rational $p > 0$ the number
> $$
> \begin{align}
> q &= p - \frac{(p^2 - 2)}{p + 2} &(2)\\
> &=\frac{2p + 2}{p + 2} &(3)\\
> &\Rightarrow q^2 - 2 = \frac{2(p^2 - 2)}{(p + 2)^2} &(4)
> \end{align}
> $$
> If $p \in A$ then $p^2 — 2 < 0$, (3) shows that $q > p$, and (4) shows that $q^2 < 2$. Thus $q \in A$. If $p \in В$ then $p^2 — 2 > 0$, (3) shows that $0 < q < p$, and (4) shows that $q^2 > 2$. Thus $q \in B$."

Are there alternative proofs that $\sup \{ p\in\mathbb{ Q}^+\mid p^2<2 \} =\sqrt 2$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169201/prove-that-the-supremum-is-sqrt2

Comment: I have a problem with OP's question. Note the discussion in OP's question is not what Rudin said: he did not say, "this proves that $\sup A = \sqrt{2}."$ Moreover, I don't think Rudin has proven $\sup A = \sqrt{2}$ in this discussion. Let's look at Rudin's definition of supremum a few pages later. If the discussion on OP's question has $S=\mathbb{R},$ then the this isn't a proof that $\sup A =\sqrt{2},$ because  irrational $\gamma$ hasn't been checked. On the other hand, if $S=\mathbb{Q},$ then $\sup A$ does not exist, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I meant that Rudin's theorem can be used to prove that $\sqrt2=\sup{S}$

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436424/prove-that-any-positive-number-has-an-nth-root

Comment: @Mathematicsenjoyer you should make your question make sense please.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $\mathbb{Q^+}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R^+_0}$ and then you have: $p \leq \sqrt{2},\forall p \in A$ and there is a sequence $(x_n),\ x_n \in \mathbb{Q^+}$, with property $x_n \in (\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n},\sqrt{2})$ (since it is dense). It is obvious that $(\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists x_n \in A)(n>\frac{1}{\epsilon})(\sqrt{2}-\epsilon< \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n}\leq x_n\leq\sqrt{2})$, meaning both conditions of a supremum are satisfied.

Comment: The problem with this i belive is your assumption that $\sqrt{2}$ exists

Comment: Yes, which can be proven.  He asked for an alternative proof and did not mention if $\sqrt{2}$ is proven to exist or not.